# Unity2018.1でCustomEditorのPreviewが表示されない

Tags: unity3d

CustomEditorのPreviewを、以下のページを参考に作成しました。
http://anchan828.github.io/editor-manual/web/customeditor.html

Unity2017.3までは正常に表示されているのを確認しているのですが、Unity2018.1.2f、Unity2018.1.5fそれぞれにアップデートして確認したところ、どちらもプレビュー画面に何も表示がされない状態になってしまいました。

Unity2018で以前通りプレビュー画面に表示させるようにするには、どのようにしたらよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
今まではこのコードで問題なかったのですが、Unity2018から仕様が変わったのか、そもそもUnity2017で描画できていたのがバグなのかという状態のようです。

該当ソースでの修正箇所は

1. Line:45/86/88 の GameObject.SetActive(true or false) を行わない
2. Line:24 の生成したGameObjectを PreviewRenderUtility.AddSingleGO(GameObject) で追加する

```
    previewObject = Instantiate (component.gameObject);
    previewRenderUtility.AddSingleGO(previewObject);
```

になります。